# Phase and frequency correct PWM mode Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega, pwm

I wrote a code to generate 1kHz Phase and frequency correct PWM signal from Arduino mega 2560 using timer 4. When I try the code with fast PWM mode it works perfectly. But phase correct mode didn't provide the expected outcome. What is wrong with my code?

```cpp
unsigned int b=7999;
void setup() {
pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
pinMode(7,OUTPUT);

TCCR4A=0;
TCCR4B=0;
//Timer 1 1kHz mode 8: phase and frequency correct pwm oc1a non inverting

TCCR4A=(1<<COM4A1)|(0<<COM4A0)|(0<<WGM41) ;//| (0<<WGM40)
TCCR4B=(1<<WGM43)|(0<<WGM42);//
ICR4=b;
OCR4A=int(b*1/5);
TCCR4B|=(1<<CS10);
TIMSK4 |=(1<<OCIE4A);
}

void loop() {
  } 

ISR(TIMER_COMPA_vect){

  }
```

The output of the code for different duty cycles are as below
**Duty cycle:0.2 (OCR4A=b/5)**
[image]

**Duty cycle:0.2 (OCR4A=b/2)**[image]

Comment: see the diagrams for pwm timing  in the datasheet

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong

Comment: in phase correct pwm the counter counts up and then down and so it matches the compare register twice in one period. first while counting up a second match while counting down. the pin changes state on both matches

Comment: That's what I need. But it's clear from the wave form that the pin trigger while down counting and resets immediately as a glitch

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> `TIMSK4 |= (1<<OCIE4A);`

and then never defined `ISR(TIMER4_COMPA_vect)`. As soon as you get a
compare match, you get a bad interrupt, which defaults to resetting your
program and restarting again from reset vector.

Comment: When I added interrupt service routine (ISR(TIMER4_COMPA_vect)) the output waveform acts exactly like fast PWM. It does not provide phase correct wave

Comment: @VivekVijayan: Do you get the expected frequency? If so, how do you tell it is not phase correct?

Comment: @Edger Bonet: I am getting the expected frequency. But when I observe the waveform all the waves with different duty cycle starts from the same point. I believe in phase correct pwm mode the OCnA or OCnB pins are set during upcounting. So I could expect different starting points(in time) for waves with different duty cycles

Comment: @VivekVijayan: You would not get 1 kHz in fast PWM mode. Re “_different starting points (in time)_”: What is your time reference for defining the starting points? Are you using an oscilloscope? If so, how did you configure its trigger?

Comment: I don't know much about CRO. I am using an electronic module called Expeyes which basically acts as a DSO. I used the time reference axis to determine the triggering points. Expeyes doesnt have any option to control triggering. I generated Fast PWM using different code and compared it with the output from the above mentioned code.

Comment: @VivekVijayan: Your phase correct waveform is fine. It looks wrong to you only because you don't understand how your DSO sets its time axis.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am proceeding with it. Will try some RC filters to identify the output waveform.